# Rudin Priciples of mathematical analysis -P316-Theorem 11.24

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\epsilon >0$ We can choose a measurable function s such that $0\leq s \leq f$, and such that $$ \int_{A_1} sd\mu \geq \int_{A_1} fd\mu-\epsilon, \space\space \int_{A_2} sd\mu \geq \int_{A_2} fd\mu - \epsilon .$$  Hence $$ \phi(A_1\cup A_2) \geq \int_{A_1\cup A_2} s d\mu =\int_{A_1} sd\mu + \int_{A_2} sd\mu \geq \phi(A_1) + \phi(A_2) - 2\epsilon ,$$ so that $$ \phi(A_1\cup A_2) \geq \phi(A_1) + \phi(A_2) .$$  I don't understand the last step in the above proof, in which $2\epsilon$ is ignored, why ? Following the same logic, I can prove $$ \phi(A_1\cup A_2) \leq \phi(A_1) + \phi(A_2) $$ since $$ \phi(A_1\cup A_2) -\epsilon \leq \int_{A_1\cup A_2} s d\mu =\int_{A_1} sd\mu + \int_{A_2} sd\mu \leq \phi(A_1) + \phi(A_2).$$ Is the above proof reasonable ?

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to this: if $x\geq y-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ then $x\geq y$.

To see this, suppose otherwise that $x<y$. Can you choose an $\epsilon$ that will lead to a contradiction?

Comment: Your reasoning is plausible only if $\epsilon \to 0 $. If $\epsilon > 0 $, then $x < y$ would not lead to a contradiction. So all proof is  meaningful only when $\epsilon =0$

Comment: The point is $\epsilon$ can get arbitrarily small while remaining positive. The premise is $x\geq y-\epsilon$ for *any* $\epsilon>0$, not *some* $\epsilon>0$.